# Requirejs reading from different modules cannot ready properly of undefined

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, requirejs

I am experimenting with require.js and am having trouble accessing module components inside of other modules. In the below example i am trying to access my junk function from my sandbox.js module inside of main. can someone help point out what i am doing wrong?

main.js

```
require.config({
     baseUrl: "assets/js",
     paths: {
        jquery: ['https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min'],
        bootstrap: ['https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js']
     }
});

require(["jquery", "sandbox"], function($, sandbox){


console.log( sandbox.junk );

});
```

Sandbox.js

```
define(['jquery'], function($){
    console.log("firebase.js is online");


    var junk = function(){
        return "tinoy";
    }

});
```

Comment: Please fix formatting!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking into it further i did the following which allows me to communicate between modules:

main.js

```
require.config({
     baseUrl: "assets/js",
     paths: {
        jquery: ['https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min'],
        bootstrap: ['https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js']
     },

     shim: {
        /* Set bootstrap dependencies (just jQuery) */
        'bootstrap' : ['jquery'],
        'firebase': {
                  exports: 'firebase'
              }
    }
});

require(["jquery", "sandbox"], function($, sandbox){

console.log( junk() );



}); //close main require
```

sandbox.js

```
define(['jquery'], function($){


    this.junk = function(){
        return "tinoy";
    }

});
```